# Excel VBA Reverse Selected Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following bit in a macro in my workbook.  It selects the last n=10 rows  to set as the data source.

```vb
.lstDbase.RowSource = "Stencils!A" & iRow - 10 & ":R" & iRow
```

Am I able to reverse this selection without actually saving the reversed data?

Comment: do you want to store the selected values in an array in reverse order ?

Comment: @ScriptDeveloper no, it just displays the recently edited value.  This gets run after a row gets inserted, then displays the last n rows.  I want to reverse just the display in the form.  I do NOT want to save the reversed data.

Comment: Can you explain a little further the scenario with some dummy data? I am not fully understanding what are you trying to achieve at the end

Comment: Could you share the relevant (complete) code? You can't reverse the range, but you can reverse an array. But you need to use `List` instead of `RowSource` to use an array... etc. Or I'm totally wrong and this doesn't relate to a list box.

Comment: A range does not have a vector, so the order of selection makes no difference (i.e. top to bottom or bottom to top). You would either need to build up an array or list of the values to use in the order you want. If you want a formula to reverse a range of values then you can use something like  `=LET(list, A2:A12, INDEX(list, 1+ROWS(list) - SEQUENCE(ROWS(list))))` (only for a single column though)

Comment: Or the much easier `=LET(data, A2:R12, SORTBY(data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),-1))` which if you save as a named range such as `Reverse` allows you to access the reversed table with `=Reverse` in the worksheet or subsequent formulae such as `=INDEX(Reverse,SEQUENCE(3),2)`

Answer (score 0):

### Get Range Rows Reverse

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateRangeRowsReverse() ' ???
    
    Const fRow As Long = 2 ' ???
    Const rMaxOffset As Long = 10
    'Const iRow As Long = 11 ' ???
        
    'With ??? 
        
        Dim lrCount As Long: lrCount = iRow - fRow + 1
        If lrCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        
        If lrCount > rMaxOffset Then lrCount = rMaxOffset
    
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stencils") _
            .Rows(iRow - lrCount + 1).Columns("A:R").Resize(lrCount)
    
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetRangeRowsReverse(rg)
    
        With .lstDbase
            .Clear
            .ColumnCount = rg.Columns.Count
            .List = Data
        End With

    'End With

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the reversed rows of a range in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRangeRowsReverse( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRangeRowsReverse"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    With rg
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        If rCount + cCount = 2 Then
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            sData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(r, c) = sData(rCount, c)
        Next c
        rCount = rCount - 1
    Next r
    
    GetRangeRowsReverse = dData
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```